# JavaScript large number library?

Tags: javascript

Is there a library available in javascript to handle large numbers with accuracy (sort of like what oracle does by storing the number as a string) and allows for operations like add/subtract/multiply/divide/mod/etc ?

Basically I need to add large numbers like 1234567890.1234567890 + 1234567890.987654321 and get a precise result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As its author, I recommend [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js), 'a small, fast Javascript library for arbitrary-precision arithmetic with decimal numbers'.

Comment: It's been years, but big.js is nice. The project I was working on back then is long gone though.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few BigInt implementations out there, for example:

- [JavaScript BigInteger Library](http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/)
- [RSA In JavaScript](http://ohdave.com/rsa/)

Layering fixed-point conversion on top of one of them should be pretty easy.

There is also a new `decimal` type in some implementations, based on a new definition from IEEE 754r — I believe it was part of the (now abandoned) ECMAScript 4 spec, and is carried forward by ECMAScript 3.1/5 and JavaScript 1.9, but I could be wrong on this point.

Comment: Native decimal support was cut from the ECMAScript 5 spec

Comment: I guess this will have to do for now. A shame JS does not have a built-in mechanism for exact math.