# Prevent JavaScript Number function from rounding big numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a string value ' 9223372036854775807 '. I use Number() function in JavaScript to convert it to a number value using the following Code

```
var numericVal = Number(' 9223372036854775807 ');
```

when i check the value in numericVal, it is 9223372036854776000. How can I get the equivalent value for the string representing the Number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725341/javascript-large-number-library

Comment: my value should be between the range -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807 hence i used the below code
`if(valueToCompare.startsWith('-')) {  
         valueToCompare = valueToCompare.substring(1);  
         isValid = !(valueToCompare>9223372036854775808);  
} else {  
          isValid = !(valueToCompare>9223372036854775807);  
}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with big numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript numbers are [Double Precision Floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision); the largest integer that can be precisely stored is 2^53 (9007199254740992). 
If you actually need it in a number you have some fun math ahead of you, or you can use a library such as [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js)

Comment: I am quite confused as the Number which came in output was bigger than the number i gave. If it can store bigger value, can't it store smaller values?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-pasted - 2^53 is 9007199254740992. It can store higher values, just not precisely.

Comment: But 9223372036854776000 is greater than 9007199254740992 right. How is this value being stored?

Comment: You are correct that it is a higher value, a `Double Precision Float` can only be precise between -2^53 and 2^53. JavaScript will attempt to store the number, but it will not be able to be precise due to the object type. Also note that JavaScript arithmetic operators work in 64-bit, but bitwise and shift operators work in 32-bits. If you are working with numbers of this size, you will need to use a non-native object such as big.js

Answer (score 3):

You can compare strings that represent big integers as strings-

a longer string of integers is larger, otherwise compare characters in order.

You can sort an array of integer-strings

```
function compareBigInts(a, b){
    if(a.length== b.length) return a>b? 1:-1;
    return a.length-b.length;
}
```

or return the larger of two strings of digits

```
function getBiggestBigInts(a, b){
    if(a.length== b.length) return a>b? a:b;
    return a.length>b.length? a: b;
}
```

//examples

```
var n1= '9223372036854775807', n2= '9223372056854775807',
n3= '9223',n2= '9223372056854775817',n4= '9223372056854775';
```

**getBiggestBigInts(n1,n2)**;>> 9223372056854775807

**[n1,n2,n3,n4].sort(compareBigInts)**;>>

```
9223
9223372056854775
9223372036854775807
9223372056854775817
```

Just make sure you are comparing **strings**.

(If you use '-' minus values,a 'bigger' string value is **less**)

By the way,you  sort big **decimals** by splitting on the decimal point and comparing the integer parts. If the integers are the same length and are equal, look at the the decimal parts.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems that your number is greater than 2^53, biggest integer number in javascript which can be represented without loosing precision (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)).

If you really need to operate big numbers, you could use special libraries like this one: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

Comment: I just want to compare this number with another. Is this possible without any special libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The problem why Number('9223372036854775807') produce 9223372036854776000 is that JavaScript have limited precision (up to 16 digits) and you need 19 digits.

One of solutions might be using of java script [big-numbers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-numbers) library:

```
// Initializa library:
var bn = new BigNumbers();

// Create numbers to compare:
var baseNumber = bn.of('9223372036854775807');
var toCompareNumber = bn.of('9223372036854775808');

// Compare:
if(baseNumber.lessOrEquals(toCompareNumber)) {
    console.log('This should be logged');
} else {
    console.log('This should NOT be logged');
}
```