# Digit loss in String to Long convertion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the  String which i need to convert the Long. I using the Number and parseFloat  digit value is getting changed 880786793918868**4786** -->> 880786793918868**5000**

> I have to convert the INC8807867939188684786 to 8807867939188684786 as
>   long or Number

```
"INC8807867939188684786".slice(3)
output :  "8807867939188684786"
```

1st Try

```
Number("INC8807867939188684786".slice(3))
 Output : 8807867939188685000
```

2nd try

```
 parseFloat("INC8807867939188684786".slice(3))
14:39:36.420 8807867939188685000
```

Comment: welcome to [64 bit floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: IEEE-754 double-precision (64 bit) gives you only 53 bits mantissa. Consider [additional libraries](https://github.com/broofa/node-int64)

Comment: from the font end (javascript/angular ) we can not get exactly  save digit ? thanks  Nina and @\aleksey  for useful knowledge update.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood biggest integer that can be precisely stored in JavaScript is 2^53 (9007199254740992). And the only way to avoid it is using libraries like  https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529337/prevent-javascript-number-function-from-rounding-big-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript number store limited number of digits (16). Generaly you can solve this problem into two ways:

1. Using strings to store your numbers (will work if you don't need to do calculations with your large numbers)
2. Use one of Big Number library for javascript. You can try [BigNumbers](http://bignumbers.tech) it is fresh, well documented and activelly supported library