# Project Euler 8. Largest product in a series

Tags: javascript

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

```
"use strict"
var data = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

function largestMulitplication(ValueOfSequence) {
    var Numbers, g = 1, ValueOfSequence, arr = [];
    Numbers = data.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        if (i == ValueOfSequence) {
            arr.push(g)
            ValueOfSequence += 4
            g = 1
        }
        g *= data[i];
    }
return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}


alert(largestMulitplication(3));
```

When ValueOfSequence has value 3 and ValueOfSequence += 4 I get 5832 and that's correct. But if I change ValueOfSequence for 29 and ValueOfSequence += 30 I get incorrect answer. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Your code only looks at sequences that do not overlap; the problem does not stipulate that constraint. So a sequence could start at position 0, or position 1, or position 2, etc.

Comment: Is this your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529337/prevent-javascript-number-function-from-rounding-big-numbers BTW. Thirteen is 13, not 30

Comment: @barbsan Oh, my bad english. But anyway I get 2477260800 instead 23514624000.

Comment: @Philip note that you omit some sequences (or, more precisely, you calculate result for some sequences, omiting huge part of them), so by accident for sequence 4 you hit winning sequence, but you miss that for sequence 13. Note also that maybe brute force is not the best way to solve this