# Why can't I get big number libraries for javascript to work?

Tags: javascript, math

Looking for a library to work with large numbers on javascript (bigger than 2^53) I checked a couple of questions ([JavaScript large number library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725341/javascript-large-number-library) and [Is there a bignum library for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript)) and then tinkered a little bit with [javascript-bignum.js](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) and [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js), but the thing is that with I am unable to represent odd numbers, since both

```
Big(9007199254740995);
```

and

```
SchemeNumber.fn["string->number"](9007199254740995);
```

return

```
9007199254740996
```

rather than

```
9007199254740995
```

as I would expect.

So, is it that I am doing something wrong? Or there's no way to represent large odd numbers?

Comment: *Usually* when handling big number libraries, you need to avoid the native number literals, in order not to "poison" your big number values with "pre-broken" values. Try if `Big("9007199254740995");` works any better.

Comment: Some examples, using a string input and a computed result using small numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/LrtrL/3/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say this

```
Big(9007199254740995)
```

you are not giving the bignum library a chance! Your numeric literal is first parsed by pure JS, in which that number isn't exactly representable. You can see this simply with

```
window.alert(9007199254740995);
```

which alerts `9007199254740996`.

In order to let your chosen bignum library successfully represent this number, you will need to **pass it as a string**, for example:

```
Big('9007199254740995')
```

should get you this exact number, as a bignum.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't thought about it.