# Calculate value of the number to be the power of more than 10,000

Tags: javascript, pow

I'm trying to calculate `Math.pow(2,1000)` and I am getting `Result : "1.0715086071862673e+301"`

If I try `Math.pow(2,10000)`, then I get `Result : "Infinity"`.

Can anyone help me to solve this using javascript?

Comment: Do you understand the magnitude of the numbers involved?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725341/javascript-large-number-library

Answer (score 2):

You can also try https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js for big number calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate such large numbers solely with JavaScript, you will probably need to use a library for that.

Please take a look at https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum or http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber